# Error: PLS-00204: function or pseudo-column 'count' may be used inside

Tags: sql, oracle

I created the following function :

```
 
    SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
    SET ECHO ON
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION count(id integer)
    RETURN integer IS 
    total integer;
    BEGIN 
    SELECT count(*) into total 
    FROM DEPARTMENTS
    where DEPARTMENTS.DEPARTMENT_ID = id;
    RETURN total; 
    END; 
    /
```

on execution the function is created but while declaring I faced the following error :

```
    DECLARE 
    i integer; 
    BEGIN 
    i := count(230); 
    dbms_output.put_line('Total no. of Customers: ' || i); 
    END; 
    /
```

Error: PLS-00204: function or pseudo-column 'count' may be used inside

Comment: count is a reserved keyword. Use some other identifier.

Comment: Ok sir let me verify !

Comment: Its working ..thanks :)